# Splat in non-final position

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8, splat

For the following method

```
def mixed_args(a,b,*c,d) 
  puts a,b,c,d
end
p mixed_args(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I get this error message:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tAMPER or '&'

Could you give me a hint what information I am missing?

Comment: This is not the answer,,*splat should be always last member in the argument list.*

Answer (score 4):

You're running Ruby 1.8. This "advanced" use of splats isn't available prior to 1.9.

In Ruby 1.8, the splat had to be the final argument: `a,b,*c` was fine. In Ruby 1.9 they introduced the ability to splat arguments mid-list, `a,b,*c,d`.

Comment: which functionality you mean? *splat* one?

Comment: Using splats mid-argument list. Clarifying answer; trying to find a decent source to link.

Comment: Humm.. that makes sense now!